# Can someone help me change this array formula to normal formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I am having problems in terms of speed with a file using this formula.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Query1[COGSDetailSKU.RecipeCode], SMALL(IF(($B$1=Query1[COGSDetailSKU.SKUName]), MATCH(ROW(Query1[COGSDetailSKU.SKUName]), ROW(Query1[COGSDetailSKU.SKUName])), ""), ROWS($A$1:B2))), "-")}
```

2 questions:
- is it possible to change it to normal formula removing only curly brackets? dos this change will make it work it at the same way?
- is t possible to recreate a formula with the functionality of the formula above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. just removing the curly brackets on older versions than the latest will not allow the formula to work.  It is an Array formula, and as is it older version require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter to force it into an array formula.  The newest version no longer requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter.
2. We can use a different type of Array formula, one that is native and does not require the use of CSE.  AGGREGATE is a natural array formula and luckily it has a `SMALL` version:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Query1[COGSDetailSKU.RecipeCode],AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(Query1[COGSDetailSKU.SKUName])-ROW(Query1[#Headers]))/($B$1=Query1[COGSDetailSKU.SKUName]),ROW(A1))), "-")
```

This formula no longer requires the use of CSE and as such the curly brackets will not be placed.

If one has the latest Excel and has access to the new Dynamic Array formula one can use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(Query1[COGSDetailSKU.RecipeCode],$B$1=Query1[COGSDetailSKU.SKUName])
```

Put that in the first cell and Excel will spill the results down automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help! the formula you create it was very useful.
What I don't understand is for what you would use the FILTER formula?
Thanks again!

Comment: The Filter formula would replace the other formula completely.  It would return the full list of `COGSDetailSKU.RecipeCode` where `COGSDetailSKU.SKUName = B1`  Without the need to copy the formula down.  It would automatically fill the column with all that match that criteria.